# check is array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, sometimes its form like:

```
//1st form    
$a = array(
    'req' => array(
        'name' => 'lia',
        'email' => 'lia@maya.com'
    )
);
 and sometime like:
//2nd form     
$a = array(
    'req' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'lia',
            'email' => 'lia@maya.com'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'citra',
            'email' => 'citra@maya.com'
        )
    )
);
```

its confused when decide to use loop. I want, if an array is like 1st form then this looping process

```
foreach ($advrs['req'] as $key => $row) {
        $emails[] = $row['email'];
    }
```

and when array in second form will use this looping process.

```
 foreach ($advrs['req'] as $key => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $list) {
            $emails[] = $list['email'];
        }
    }
```

how to make it? thank you.

Comment: I find it odd that the first example, the non array version, is setup like that when you could just as easily place it in the same format as the 2nd form, which will be more common for this type of structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `is_array` like

```
foreach ($advrs['req'] as $key => $row) {
    if(is_array($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $list) {
            $emails[] = $list['email'];
        }
    } else {
        $emails[] = $row['email'];
    } 
}
```